# How to run html code before php in order to create imgs first?

Tags: php

I have a php code that is sending an email, the problem is that i need to print images before the php actually send the email like

```
<img src="../graphics/g_builder.php?type=funil&interval=1&time=<?php print time(); ?>"/>
<img src="../graphics/g_builder.php?type=funil&interval=3&time=<?php print time(); ?>"/>
```

Or so the email goes empty and the images are created and if i try again the email goes perfect.

I just need a way to run that code somehow before sending the email any idea?

Complementing

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->IsSMTP();
$email->isHTML(true);
$email->CharSet   = 'UTF-8';
$email->From      = 'king@graphics.com';
$email->FromName  = 'King Graphics';
$email->Subject   = 'Gráficos de Conversão dos novos usuários';
$email->AddAddress( 'thiago.sabin@jogosdorei.com.br' );

$email->AddEmbeddedImage("../img/funilDiario.png", "f_diario", "funilDiario.png");
```

and a string holding my email body with

```
$email->Body='html stuff';
```

and after all that

```
$email->Send();
```

So the php look for images in a folder that may not have the images so im using the

```
<img src="../graphics/g_builder.php?type=funil&interval=1&time=<?php print time(); ?>"/>
```

To create them before sending the email but the email is being sended first an the images are being created later ;/

Comment: Can you post your code, or the relevant parts at least, so we can see what you're attempting to send?

Comment: yeah, question isn't really clear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: How your code is written is PHP will write the time, making the URL for your src attribute the URL you have, plus the date at the end. When the email is received, the client will load the URL of the image. Unless I'm misunderstanding you, assuming your g builder works as you intend, you should be okay.

Comment: Now it's better, uploaded the question

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is simply run your image builder code before sending the email. There are different ways to accomplish this, but here's a very basic example:

```
// create an image on the file system
function graphicBuilder($type, $interval, $time) {
    // do something
    ...
}

// generate the image and return a /path/to/file
$filename = graphicBuilder('funil', 1, time());

// email the message with links to the image
$email = new PHPMailer();
...
$email->AddEmbeddedImage("../img/funilDiario.png", "f_diario", "funilDiario.png");
$email->Body = '<img src="' . $filename . '" />';
$email->Send();
```

The solution should be that simple.